# Firefox screen flickers when resizing

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, svg, d3.js

I am facing a flickering issue, on re-sizing, with my Firefox web browser. I think it is because of the use of SVGs on the page. I tried adding the transition css property by referring the following links, but didn't help. 
 
1. https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/can-i-stop-flickering-on-hover/. 
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions

Any help or a starting reference would be appreciated. Thank you. I am new with css. One more thing, the screen does not flicker in Chrome or IE. I hope this information helps and this is not a stupid question.

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle or your page or anything where the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: Hello, @Xufox. Thank you for your reply. I have never used JSFiddle before. Before I reproduce the issue I would like to let you know that the page is using D3 graphs and they flicker (along with everything else) while resizing.

Comment: Yeah, you can select “D3” as a library on the left side of the JSFiddle page.